# Apply correct model according to available non-missing column data

Tags: r

`Sample data:`

```
var1 <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:3), 10, replace = TRUE), 10,1)
var2 <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:3), 10, replace = TRUE), 10,1)
var3 <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:3), 10, replace = TRUE), 10,1)
var4 <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:3), 10, replace = TRUE), 10,1)
var5 <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:3), 10, replace = TRUE), 10,1)

NewDataframe <- as.data.frame(cbind(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5))
names(NewDataframe) <- c("var1","var2","var3","var4","var5")

NewDataframe[is.na(NewDataframe)] <- ""
```

`vector of data:`

```
par1 <- data.frame(var1=2,var3=5,var4=3)
par2 <- data.frame(var2=4,var5=7)
```

Pre-multiply each row of newdataframe with the correct `par` variables `var1` atc. 
Rows where `par1` or `par2` would not apply is left blank. How to approach this? Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly you have two models: preferred but with more variables (and higher likelihood of `NA`), and less detailed (but more robust to `NA`). You want to selectively pick estimates, preferring the first model, an using the second in case it can't get an estimate. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. I'm about to simplify my question. Hope I get it right and right to the point this time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have simplified some of your code to use `predict()` as a much handier alternative to doing the matrix multiplication yourself.

```
dataframe <- data.frame(y=rbinom(100,2,0.4),var1=rnorm(100,2,2),var2=rnorm(100,3,4),var3=rnorm(100,4,5),var4=rnorm(100,5,6),var5=rnorm(100,30,3))

model1 <- lm(y~var1+var3, data=dataframe)
model2 <- lm(y~var2+var4+var5, data=dataframe)

var1 <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:3), 100, replace = TRUE), 100,1)
var2 <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:3), 100, replace = TRUE), 100,1)
var3 <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:3), 100, replace = TRUE), 100,1)
var4 <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:3), 100, replace = TRUE), 100,1)
var5 <- matrix(sample(c(NA, 1:3), 100, replace = TRUE), 100,1)

NewDataframe <- as.data.frame(cbind(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5))
names(NewDataframe) <- c("var1","var2","var3","var4","var5")
```

Use `complete.cases()` to identify rows that have no `NA`s and would produce a viable estimate

```
m1.ids <- with(NewDataframe, complete.cases(var1, var3))
```

Make two vectors, one using `model1` for the rows that have no `NA`s in the relevant columns, and another using `model2` for all the rest.

```
y.hat1 <- predict(model1, newdata=NewDataframe[m1.ids, ])
y.hat2 <- predict(model2, newdata=NewDataframe[!m1.ids, ])
```

Use the index to match the estimates to their respective rows.

```
NewDataframe <- rbind(data.frame(NewDataframe[m1.ids,], y.hat=y.hat1),
                      data.frame(NewDataframe[!m1.ids,], y.hat=y.hat2))
```

Alternatively, you can generate a full vector of estimates with each model, and use `ifelse()` to choose values from the second if the first is `NA`. That could look cleaner if your data is not big, but would produce redundant estimates.